# How to split a string into regular intervals in R?

Tags: r, split

I have a long string that I want to split into regular intervals of, say, 10 words each:

```
x <- "Hrothgar, king of the Danes, or Scyldings, builds a great mead-hall, or palace, in which he hopes to feast his liegemen and to give them presents. The joy of king and retainers is, however, of short duration. Grendel, the monster, is seized with hateful jealousy. He cannot brook the sounds of joyance that reach him down in his fen-dwelling near the hall. Oft and anon he goes to the joyous building, bent on direful mischief. Thane after thane is ruthlessly carried off and devoured, while no one is found strong enough and bold enough to cope with the monster. For twelve years he persecutes Hrothgar and his vassals."
```

Using `strsplit` I can split the sentence into individual words:

```
x1 <- unlist(strsplit(x, " "))
```

Using `paste` I can paste together 10 words each:

```
paste(x1[1:10], collapse = " ")
paste(x1[11:20], collapse = " ")
...
paste(x1[101:110], collapse = " ")
```

But that's tedious, so I've tried `sapply` and `seq`:

```
lapply(x1, function(x) paste(x[seq(1,100,10)], collapse = " "))
```

but the result is not what I want. What I want is something like this:

```
[1] "Hrothgar, king of the Danes, or Scyldings, builds a great"
[2] "mead-hall, or palace, in which he hopes to feast his"
[3] "liegemen and to give them presents. The joy of king"
[4] "and retainers is, however, of short duration. Grendel, the monster,"
[5] "is seized with hateful jealousy. He cannot brook the sounds"
...
[10] "twelve years he persecutes Hrothgar and his vassals. NA NA"
```

I'm open to any solution but would be particularly grateful for a `base R` one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a sequence and paste the words from `x1` :

```
sapply(seq(1, length(x1), 10), function(i) 
       paste0(x1[i:min(i + 9, length(x1))], collapse = " "))

# [1] "Hrothgar, king of the Danes, or Scyldings, builds a great"          
# [2] "mead-hall, or palace, in which he hopes to feast his"               
# [3] "liegemen and to give them presents. The joy of king"                
# [4] "and retainers is, however, of short duration. Grendel, the monster,"
# [5] "is seized with hateful jealousy. He cannot brook the sounds"        
# [6] "of joyance that reach him down in his fen-dwelling near"            
# [7] "the hall. Oft and anon he goes to the joyous"                       
# [8] "building, bent on direful mischief. Thane after thane is ruthlessly"
# [9] "carried off and devoured, while no one is found strong"             
#[10] "enough and bold enough to cope with the monster. For"               
#[11] "twelve years he persecutes Hrothgar and his vassals."
```

Comment: A beautiful solution. Could you elaborate on this part: `x1[i:min(i + 9, length(x1))]`?

Comment: `x1[i:(i + 9)]` selects 10 words each. For the last iteration `i + 9` would give you 110 but you only have 108 words in x1. So I use `min(i + 9, length(x1))` indicating take minimum of `i+9` or `length(x1)`.

Answer (score 5):

Another option with only `base R`, using `regex` to capture (`\\1`) groups of 10 words (alphanumeric characters, which may contain hyphen, with a word bound `\b`), and punctuations, and put a "remarkable" string (`"XXX"` here) in the end, so it can be split by this string afterwards (putting a space before this string in the `strsplit` pattern avoids trailing space at the end of each bit):

```
unlist(strsplit(gsub("(((\\w|-)+\\b[ ,.]*){10})", "\\1XXX", x), " XXX"))

# [1] "Hrothgar, king of the Danes, or Scyldings, builds a great"          
# [2] "mead-hall, or palace, in which he hopes to feast his"               
# [3] "liegemen and to give them presents. The joy of king"                
# [4] "and retainers is, however, of short duration. Grendel, the monster,"
# [5] "is seized with hateful jealousy. He cannot brook the sounds"        
# [6] "of joyance that reach him down in his fen-dwelling near"            
# [7] "the hall. Oft and anon he goes to the joyous"                       
# [8] "building, bent on direful mischief. Thane after thane is ruthlessly"
# [9] "carried off and devoured, while no one is found strong"             
#[10] "enough and bold enough to cope with the monster. For"               
#[11] "twelve years he persecutes Hrothgar and his vassals."
```

Comment: Very nice. Playing with your pattern I've also found this `stringr` solution: `str_extract_all(x, "((\\w|-)+\\b[ ,.]*){1,10}")`

Comment: `stringr` functions can indeed be of help but then it's not a `base R` solution anymore ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gregexpr` with `regmatches` and quantify the words with `{1,10}`.

```
trimws(regmatches(x, gregexpr("([^[:space:]]+\\s*){1,10}", x))[[1]])
# [1] "Hrothgar, king of the Danes, or Scyldings, builds a great"          
# [2] "mead-hall, or palace, in which he hopes to feast his"               
# [3] "liegemen and to give them presents. The joy of king"                
# [4] "and retainers is, however, of short duration. Grendel, the monster,"
# [5] "is seized with hateful jealousy. He cannot brook the sounds"        
# [6] "of joyance that reach him down in his fen-dwelling near"            
# [7] "the hall. Oft and anon he goes to the joyous"                       
# [8] "building, bent on direful mischief. Thane after thane is ruthlessly"
# [9] "carried off and devoured, while no one is found strong"             
#[10] "enough and bold enough to cope with the monster. For"               
#[11] "twelve years he persecutes Hrothgar and his vassals."
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this might help

```
sapply(
  unname(split(
    y <- unlist(strsplit(x, " ")),
    ceiling(seq_along(y) / 10)
  )),
  paste,
  collapse = " "
)
```

which gives

```
 [1] "Hrothgar, king of the Danes, or Scyldings, builds a great"
 [2] "mead-hall, or palace, in which he hopes to feast his"
 [3] "liegemen and to give them presents. The joy of king"
 [4] "and retainers is, however, of short duration. Grendel, the monster,"
 [5] "is seized with hateful jealousy. He cannot brook the sounds"
 [6] "of joyance that reach him down in his fen-dwelling near"
 [7] "the hall. Oft and anon he goes to the joyous"
 [8] "building, bent on direful mischief. Thane after thane is ruthlessly"
 [9] "carried off and devoured, while no one is found strong"
[10] "enough and bold enough to cope with the monster. For"
[11] "twelve years he persecutes Hrothgar and his vassals."
```

Answer (score 1):

using stringr:

```
library(stringr)
N = length(strsplit(x, ' ')[[1]]) 
start = seq.int(1, N, 10)
end = start+9
end[length(end)] = N
word(x, start, end)

# [1] "Hrothgar, king of the Danes, or Scyldings, builds a great"          
# [2] "mead-hall, or palace, in which he hopes to feast his"               
# [3] "liegemen and to give them presents. The joy of king"                
# [4] "and retainers is, however, of short duration. Grendel, the monster,"
# [5] "is seized with hateful jealousy. He cannot brook the sounds"        
# [6] "of joyance that reach him down in his fen-dwelling near"            
# [7] "the hall. Oft and anon he goes to the joyous"                       
# [8] "building, bent on direful mischief. Thane after thane is ruthlessly"
# [9] "carried off and devoured, while no one is found strong"             
# [10] "enough and bold enough to cope with the monster. For"               
# [11] "twelve years he persecutes Hrothgar and his vassals."
```

Comment: Thanks. `lengths(strsplit(x, ' '))` works too. Is this really `stringr` (you're using `strsplit` not `str_split`)?

Comment: `word` is from stringr.  The rest is base R